# Как заставить потоки следовать выполняться в определенном порядке

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть класс Number, в котором три метода

```
print("1");
print("2");
print("3");
```

Экземпляр класса Number будет передан в три потока, в котором он будет вызывать методы. Мы не знаем, в каком порядке будут вызваны методы, как реализовать, чтобы в любом случае на выходе мы получили

```
"1, 2, 3" ?
```

Comment: не передавать в потоки, а выполнять последовательно?

Comment: нет, именно передать в потоки, но чтобы потоки выполнялись всегда так, чтобы как бы мы их не вызвали, в какой последовательности, они выполнились, как "1,2,3"

Comment: Поместить все три принта в `synchronized` секцию